java.sql.SQLException: ORA-28274: No ORACLE password attribute corresponding to user nickname exists
I have application which is connecting to database. Database is up and running because I can connect to it via SQLDeveloper (so I also know that credentials are correct).
However when I try to connect from application I have an error:
09:27:06.190 [com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0] DEBUG com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool - An exception occurred while acquiring a poolable resource. Will retry.
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-28274: No ORACLE password attribute corresponding to user nickname exists.

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:331)

09:27:06.200 [com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0] WARN com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool - com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@58c010ac -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception: 
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-28274: No ORACLE password attribute corresponding to user nickname exists.

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)

What can be possible problem here?
@Edit
I added test which is using the same code - Handle h = open(); and it works in test but still doesn't work on Tomcat
I am using ojdbc-8 19.3.0.0 with Java 8.

This is a database administration problem and not a programming problem and is off-topic for StackOverflow. See https://docs.oracle.com/en/error-help/db/ora-28274/ for details of the error - your LDAP entries are not correctly provisioned.

It's not about LDAP but rather libraries jdbi and ojdbc
